# On page load RadButton Onclientclicked triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

When I use telerik radbutton

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="Stackoverflow" 
Skin="Default" OnClientClicked="SaveIt()" CommandArgument="Edit">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

after refreshing page, always SaveIt() function starts to work.
But;
when I use button, it works only when user click it.

```
<button type="button" onclick="SaveIt()">Stackoverflow</button>
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of things here. The difference between a RadButton and a normal HTML button is as follows:

When a RadButton is used, the client side HTML generated is as follows:

```
<a id="btnStandard" class="RadButton RadButton_Office2010Silver rbSkinnedButton"
  href="javascript:void(0)">
    <input class="rbDecorated" type="submit" name="btnStandard_input" 
      id="btnStandard_input" value="Standard Button" />
    <input id="btnStandard_ClientState" name="btnStandard_ClientState"
      type="hidden" />
</a>
```

As you can see, the  type generated is of "Submit" - which means it will submit the form to the server. So if you refresh it will try to resend the form again. 
what i am failing to understand is - have you used ajax panel. Because if you have used ajax panel, the button click would trigger an ajax posting to the server and when you refresh the page its as if its a first time and not a postback.

Where as the normal html  is not meant for form submits. Its just used to trigger a click event on the client side.

Having said that - the signature for OnClientChecked is as follows:

```
OnClientChecked="<js function name>"
```

NOTE: you should be providing only the function name without parenthesis i.e. ( and ).

In your case since you provided the parenthesis - when the button gets initialized the client side functions associated with it are getting executed and you are having your Javascript code run at runtime.

So here is the right code for this:

```
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" Text="test" OnClientClicked="func" />

<script>
    function func() {
        alert("clicked");
    }
</script>
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: have you tested this at all??

Comment: Its worked :) Thanks Lohith, We met at KMug Sessions. Happy to see you here.

Comment: Great, it works!.

But how to pass other control clientID to that function?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the RadButton have the onClick methods instead of OnClientClicked ?

Comment: 'OnClick' is a serverside method. the control would have absolutely no use to anyone if it did not hav a server click event...
Also a question like this should be inside a comment, not posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've run into this behavior also. Refreshing the page does imply a postback as the person who posted the alleged answer for this claims. The js function specified for the onclientclicked event is firing on the loading of the page. I noticed the answer simply re-stated the obvious and what the original poster had posted as the code that is not working and claimed it worked without addressing the issue of the function being fired on load and simply assumed a 'refresh' was equivalent to a postback.

I simply thought I'd address to fish for a valid analysis and to point out simply that if someone posts something and their friend promotes it as an answer, it doesn't mean it's right.

Comment: Give that man a Bells! @kashyapa did not give the answer at all.